# Can a fluid body in Blender be displaced by a hollow solid?

Tags: ocean-simulation

I am doing a series of demo videos where a hull is immersed in a fluid like a mesh with the Ocean modifier, (but it could be something else).

Tutorials and other references show boats parented to planes shrink-wrapped to the surface of the fluid. But this only causes the vessel to take the motion and rotation imparted by the surface; it doesn't have any effect on the fluid surface at all.

In the examples I've found, the kludge is the the boats have decks that are above the waterline. But in a case where there is no deck, the water surface simply carries on through the hull, effectively showing it flooded. This is not the effect I need.

Is there a way to perform something like a dynamic Boolean operation, where the hull, whose position is determined in the way the tutorials show (not perfect, but useable for my needs) can remove its own outside shape from the fluid?

I don't need a full buoyancy physics engine here, that calculates actual immersion in the water. As I say, the method shown is fine. But I need to not have water in the bottom of my boat.